# How to resolve uncaught syntax error in jsonp

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, jquery

I am accessing a cross domain api using jquery ajax but I can't achieve it . Iam getting error as "uncaught syntaxerror : unexpected token <" in the console, How to fix this.

**Code:**

```
$.ajax({ 
url: "http://..............", 
type:"GET", 
dataType: 'jsonp', 
crossDomain: true, 
contentType:"application/javascript", 
success: function (data) { 
    alert(data);
}, 
error: function (errorMEssage, Errtext) { 
    alert(Errtext);
} 
});
```

**Error:**

```
uncaught syntaxerror : unexpected token <
```

Comment: What does the server return? Does it support JSONP?

Comment: change `dataType` to `xml` then

Comment: @user1671639 iam not passing any data iam just retrieving everything in the api

Comment: But that won't work. You cannot use XML for cross domain AJAX calls.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot make cross domain AJAX calls using JSONP to a server that returns XML. If you want to be able to make a cross domain AJAX call you have 2 possibilities:

- use [`JSONP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) -> your server needs to support it.
- use [`CORS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) -> your server **AND** client browser need t support it.

If your server supports CORS your request may look like this:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "http://..............", 
    type:"GET", 
    crossDomain: true, 
    success: function (data) { 
        alert(data);
    }, 
    error: function (errorMEssage, Errtext) { 
        alert(Errtext);
    } 
});
```

Comment: Use JSONP or CORS. You will need to modify the remote endpoint to support one of the 2. Only then you will be able to make cross domain AJAX calls.

Comment: NO. CORS means Cross Origin Resource Sharing. Please read the article I have linked to in my answer. Your server side script will need to send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response headers to an OPTIONS verb request. Once you ensure that the remote server sends this header you could remove the `dataType: 'jsonp'` parameter from your AJAX call.

Comment: but the thing is iam getting 200 success and in console  if i click that error i can able able to view xml response

Comment: Then maybe the server already supports CORS. Try removing the `dataType: 'jsonp'` parameter. Also change the `contentType` parameter.

Comment: don't specify dataType parameter, remove that  is that you are saying

Answer (score 0):

change the dataType to **`xml`**

```
dataType: 'xml',
```

Comment: @DarinDimitrov +1 Thanks, I was looking in the CORS that you have referred.

Comment: @Praveen can you share that link in here please